# How to get rid of wanted tag?

Tags: elite-dangerous

How can I get rid of the wanted tag? When I try and leave the station the security just destroys the ship straight away. I don't have anything in my cargo. Is there a timer before it goes away?

Comment: You are wanted because you have an unpaid fine. You need to pay it to become "unwanted".

Comment: Any 2.0 update? I just got a bounty and when I go to the station I can't pay anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This information is out of date as of version 1.3 of the game.**

No, there is no timer. If you are Wanted you will have a bounty on your head. To clear the "wanted" tag you must pay the bounty.

You can do this by docking at any space station and going to Contacts -> Pilot's Federation. If you are currently docked, this is easy. If you are in space then if you will not be allowed to dock with a station that is controlled by the faction that you are wanted with (and they will shoot at you too). In this case you will need to fly to a station belonging to somebody else to pay the fine.

NB Information based on gamma test; may not apply to release version.

Comment: If you're wanted, you can dock in "silent running" mode. The ships outside do the scan that leads to shooting you. Basically: stay 7km+ away from the station, get lined up, set power distribution to full engine, turn everything off (maybe except life support), wait for your ship to cool down to 10% or lower, enable "silent running", turn thrusters back on, request docking, and dock quickly. If you disable flight assist you might be able to drift into the station with all systems off. If you upgrade your life support you can get more time with it off before you're out of oxygen.

Comment: @freiheit pretty sure that your docking request will be denied if you're a criminal with the faction that controls the station.

Comment: @SimonW You definitely cannot pay a fine at a station not controlled by the faction you owe the fine to. I encountered that situation and had to fly to another station in the system to pay the fine before it turned to a warrant. The only wanted/warrant I ever had was Pilots Federation and I did the silent entry and didn't get the usual security scan "you're clear now" thing. (All in Gamma)

Comment: @CmdrFreiheit (revistiing after ages) I think there is a confusion here between fines and bounties. Fines don't stop you docking, and perhaps must be paid to the relevant faction. Bounties (being "wanted") do stop you docking - you can't get permission if you're a criminal - but can be paid off anywhere.

Comment: When I was in an Empire-controlled system running bounties, I accidentally shot an Imperial Navy Officer and got a 400 credit bounty on my head. I was unable to dock at the local city, because they "don't allow criminals". I was forced to use the local outpost instead to pay it off. However, when I've had a fine for dumping cargo, I've been ok to pay it off in the city.

Answer (score 13):

As of the 1.3 Power Play update, this has now changed.

There are two types of status illict activities can net you:

- A Fine: Ships will not  pursue you and will not attack you. You must pay this fine off at a station affiliated with the faction that issued the fine. If you do not pay off the fine, it will eventually turn into a bounty.
- A Bounty: You can no longer pay off your bounty. Instead, bounties will simply expire after some time. Currently that seems to range from 12 hours to 1 week.

If you do incur a bounty, you can simply leave that space until the bounty expires. If you choose the stay in the space, you will show up as 'Wanted' and other NPCs and CMDRs will target you for it.

It is also possible to buy a sidewinder and let a npc in the wanted space kill you. This allows them to collect the bounty and you will be able to pay a small insurance fee and respawn without the bounty.

Comment: How long do you think, say, a 400cr bounty last? Accidentally fired at someone because I forgot to reset my firegroups.

Comment: I'd imagine somewhere in the range of 15 minutes to 12 hours. However there simply isn't enough info floating around right now to say for sure.

Comment: A single small bounty (400Cr assault) only lasts 15 minutes. If you commit another crime in that system, your bounty will go up appropriately, and the time will increase. Eventually it gets up to a full week. I believe any crime in that system in that week resets the timer to a full week. I'm not sure what the intermediate steps are between 15 minutes and one week. I've been testing this thoroughly with PowerPlay undermining, but I don't usually check my transactions panel until after a lot of "murders".

Comment: Getting scanned by that faction can also reset the bounty timer. See: http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty

Answer (score 1):

The Transactions page tells you how long you have to pay the fine and how long any bounty will remain live. It gave me a scare when I got one (I was supposed to disable the ships in a mission, not kill them!). I got a 6.5K bounty and wanted status in that system for 6 days.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020, it seems if you are [wanted](https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Bounty), you can either:

- **Get caught** and destroyed by security ships. You will be transported to a detention center, and have to repurchase your ship.
- **Turn yourself in** to one of the contacts (at a station aligned with the faction you are wanted by). You will be transported to a detention center, but you get to **keep your current ship**.
- **Pay off the bounty** against you, by finding a contact who is an Interstellar Factor.

  > [Interstellar Factor](https://elite-dangerous.fandom.com/wiki/Interstellar_Factor) contacts are generally found in systems with low security. To identify systems with an Interstellar Factor, open the Galaxy Map and set it to map mode. Then, select "Services" from the drop-down menu and check "Interstellar Factors".

In the op's case, if he cannot escape the station's security forces, than handing himself in might be the preferable option.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because I had a meager one(286cr) but it seems my fine was removed with a small wait and hyperspace jump.

Comment: You likely jumped out of the space that you were wanted in.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally shot a 'clean' one during a dog fight at one of the nav beacons. Got a 400cr bounty. Under transactions it said "On H-Jump". So I jumped to another system and the entry was gone from the transactions tab.
However, after docking at the next station and going to the Local Security Office under Contacts there was a new entry under 'Legacy Fines' for 400cr from that earlier incident. There you select to pay the bounty that turned into a fine.
A bit confusing how they change from bounty to fine.